# Is `{}` functionally equivalent to `not null & not undefined`?

Tags: typescript, types, negation

I'm in a situation where I'd like to type a value as "anything except undefined". I know the type `{}` represents an empty object, and since every value in JavaScript is an object except for `undefined` and `null`, `{}` seems to be equivalent to `not null & not undefined` (if there was some theoretical negating `not` operator in TypeScript).

Is this a sound assumption? Are there any types at all besides `null` and `undefined` that are not assignable to `{}`?

Comment: "..since every value in JavaScript is an object except.." - that's an incorrect premise. For example, `42` is not an object as it has a type `number`. The corresponding object would be `Number(42)`, which is of type `Number`.

Comment: We can charitably change that to "every value except `null` and `undefined` can be indexed into as if it were an object without getting a runtime error"

Comment: And yes, `{}` is essentially `not (null | undefined)` in terms of what values it accepts.  There might be some fiddly stuff with the `void` type but it's more or less correct... so "anything except undefined" would be `{} | null`

Comment: Let me know if you think this question is not answered by the linked question above.  It would be great if the TypeScript Handbook had documentation for the empty object type but it doesn't seem to.  There's [microsoft/TypeScript#10715](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10715), proposing `unknown` and if/how that would be different from `{} | null | undefined`.  The actual `unknown` is not seen as equivalent to `{} | null | undefined` although just about every value is assignable to either one.

Comment: @jcalz That definitely answers it, thanks.